# How to create C# string object inside .ps1 file

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-4.0

The below C# snippet is embedded in a powershell (.ps1) file and generated an System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException. Removing "string s" and the exception goes away. Tried to use uppercase "String" and tried to add namespace "System.String" and various other approaches but still get the exception. This is driving me nuts, please help me understand why this is happening.

```
$code = @"
public static class foo
{
  public static bool check()
  {
    string s;
    return false;
  }
}
```

Code is invoked like this;

```
try
{
  Add-Type -TypeDefinition $code -Language CSharp
}
catch{} // ignore TYPE_ALREADY_EXISTS exception
$res = [foo]::check();
```

Here is exception details;

```
Exception: System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: unable to find type [foo].
TargetObject: foo
CategoryInfo: InvalidOperation (foo:Typename) [], RuntimeException
FullyQualifiedErrorId: TypeNotFound
InvocationInfo: System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo
```

Comment: Please post enough code so that we can at least reproduce the issue. Defining the string value `$code` obviously won't compile your class on it's own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$code = @"
public static class foo {
  public static bool check() {
    string s;
    return false;
  }
}
"@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $code -Language CSharp
```

produces

> Warning as Error: The variable 's' is declared but never used

It will not allow you to declare unused variables.

Comment: There's a simple solution to that, but we don't know what OP is actaully doing

Comment: Yeah I know. That's why I left it as is. This was too long for a comment.

Comment: Your answer help me understand how to better develop C# code in the context of powershell. Thank you.